# Create multiple grunt task

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

```
watch: {
    css: {
        files: 'source/styles/**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin', 'clean:css'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        },
    },
    images: {
        files: 'source/assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
        tasks: ['clean:image', 'imagemin'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        },
    }
}



grunt.registerTask('css', [
    'sass',
    'cssmin',
    'clean:css'
]);



sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['source/styles/**/*.scss'],
            dest: 'build/styles/',
            ext: '.css',
            flatten: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        compass: true,
        sourcemap: false
    }
}


grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'sass',
    'cssmin',
    'clean:css',
    'requirejs',
    'clean:js',
]);
```

I want to create a new gurnt task. Currenly, In my project, `grunt css` is working fine to build the complate packae SCSS.
I need to create a new task like `grunt home`, which will build a specific folder SCSS.

How can I create `grunt home`?

Comment: `grunt.registerTask('gruntHome', ['homeSASS'])` maybe this way? Next step create homeSASS like sass, but with diffrent dest

Comment: will you please explain how to create this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but i didn't test it (it will compile SCSS files from source/styles/SCSS to css in build/styles/css):

```
homeSass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['source/styles/SCSS/**/*.scss'],
            dest: 'build/styles/css/',
            ext: '.css',
            flatten: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        compass: true,
        sourcemap: false
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('homebuild', [
    'homeSass'
]);
```

Is it your are looking for? Or I misunderstand you?

Comment: It's showing error: 

Warning: Task "homeSass" not found. Use --force to continue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am looking for the same thing.

Here is my edited code https://jsfiddle.net/nsj3r9Lm/ but its throwing error: `Warning: Task "homeSass" not found. Use --force to continue.`

Comment: Add `grunt.registerTask('homebuild', ['homeSass']);` and start via `gulp homebuild`

Answer (score 0):

so something like this you can create multiple tasks

```
sass2: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['source/styles/**/*.scss'],//path to different source file
            dest: 'build/styles/',//path to different destination for home
            ext: '.css',
            flatten: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        compass: true,
        sourcemap: false
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('home', [
    'sass2'
]);
```

Now to run this you have 2 ways

1) simply say `grunt home`
this will only run sass compilation specific to sass2

2) now if you wants to run both the tasks `grunt css` and `grunt home` in 1 go then do this

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['source/styles/**/src1.scss', 'source/styles/**/src2.scss'],
            dest: 'build/styles/',
            ext: '.css',
            flatten: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        compass: true,
        sourcemap: false
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('home', [
    'sass'
]);
```

Comment: Should it not be `grunt home` etc not `gulp`?

Comment: Yes correct grunt home, sorry my bad start using gulp for few weeks thats why this gulp is moving in my mind

Comment: You're not the only one. @guest mentions it in the comments too: "gulp homebuild" so I didn't know if this was just coincidence or if I was missing something!